# UIStoryboard with object

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have multiple storyboards within my app. I want to pass an object when a new storyboard is opened.

I'am doing this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SetupStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController* initialHelpView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

SetupViewController *setup = (SetupViewController*) [initialHelpView topViewController];
setup.data = self.data;

initialHelpView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:initialHelpView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when the storyboard is presented the `setup.data` is `nil` in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc of the `SetupViewController`...

Why is that?

Comment: Have you logged self.data to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: i'am positive that self.data is not nil.

Comment: How are you declaring data in SetupViewController?

Comment: I have declared data as a property:
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *data;

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try logging setup's class to make sure it's correct.

Comment: well, it seems that [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SetupStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 creates my controller and [initialHelpView topViewController]; creates another controller making the addresses different.. why can that be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36130/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-rasmus-styrk)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with this code. Problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: Try checking it...

SetupViewController *setup = (SetupViewController*) [initialHelpView topViewController];
setup.data = self.data;

//here.

initialHelpView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;